# C# How to replace 0 (zero) with space

Tags: c#, replace, space, zero

I want to replace 0 (zero) with space in Nr string variable:

```
return new FaultEntity()
{
   Nr = token[0]=="0"?" ":token[0],
   ...
};
```

If Nr = '0' i want to replace with space, replacing simple Nr = token[0] in collection.

I think that can be replaces by something like that:

string Nr = string.IsZero(token[0]) ? "0" : token[0],

How can I do that, in a simple way ?

I edit with solition. Thanks.

Comment: Your code doesn't really have anything to do with replacing or removing text. Are you trying to replace "a0c" with "a c"?

Comment: Also note that `Nr` is just an int, presumably... an int can't have spaces, nor does it really have digits, as such... it's just an integer number within a particular range. (It could be expressed in various different bases - 10 in decimal has a 0 in, but the exact same value in hex doesn't.)

Comment: convert it to string and you can use trim for pre and post spaces or you can use replace as suggested by @shamim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
return new FaultEntity()
{
   Nr = token[0]=="0"?" ":token[0],
   ...
};
```

for an integer value

```
int data = 10102;
string st = data.ToString();
var con = st.Replace('0', ' ');
```

Comment: Thank you, but I receive an Error Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'char'.

Comment: @popad please check now

Comment: I try this:   return new FaultEntity()
   {
      Nr = token[0]=='0'?' ':token[0],
      ...
   }; same error

Comment: what is the data type of Nr and token[0]?

Comment: I replace ' ' with " " and work now. ' ' for char and " " for string. Missing that. Thank you for help.